# Rails4 iterate through nested params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes

I am trying to iterate through a nested hash to access two separate fields. This is what I am trying to do:

1. Check to see if `:is_cover_photo` is true
2. if `:is_cover_photo` is true then I want to call the update method on `@point_of_interest`.

I keep getting an error thrown and cannot figure out how to accomplish this task.

This is error I am getting: `"no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"`

This is in my `update` method of `point_of_interests_controller`:

```
  def update
    @point_of_interest = PointOfInterest.find(params[:id])

    if @point_of_interest.update(params[:point_of_interest].permit(:title, :caption, :website, :summary, :latitude, :longitude, :cover_photo, albums_attributes: [:id, :cover_photo, :title, :is_cover_photo]))
      params[:point_of_interest][:albums_attributes].each do |key, value|
        value.each do |k, v|
          if k[:is_cover_photo] && k[:cover_photo].blank?
            @point_of_interest.update(:cover_photo => k[:cover_photo])
          end   
        end  
      end
      redirect_to @point_of_interest
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
    end
```

Here are the parameters being passed:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"XGvgfxFHZKpiE8eGqc+55qOlSSk9LYFGdywWyABezXo=",
 "point_of_interest"=>{"title"=>"WolfieOne",
 "latitude"=>"33.577836",
 "longitude"=>"-85.074692",
 "caption"=>"CaptionOne",
 "website"=>"google.com",
 "summary"=>"This is a test summary.",
 "albums_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"Album Uno",
 "cover_photo"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000000113ae4c0 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:C:/Users/Samuel/AppData/Local/Temp/RackMultipart20140220-7188-4ptfo1>,
 @original_filename="Lighthouse.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg",
 @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"point_of_interest[albums_attributes][0][cover_photo]\"; filename=\"Lighthouse.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">,
 "is_cover_photo"=>"1",
 "id"=>"23"},
 "1"=>{"title"=>"Album 2",
 "is_cover_photo"=>"0",
 "id"=>"24"},
 "2"=>{"title"=>"The Best Album Alive",
 "is_cover_photo"=>"0",
 "id"=>"30"}}},
 "commit"=>"Submit Wolfie",
 "id"=>"15"}
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

This resolved the issue for me:Thanks to Coenwulf

```
params[:point_of_interest][:albums_attributes].each do |key, value|
  if value[:is_cover_photo] && value[:cover_photo].present?
    @point_of_interest.update(:cover_photo => value[:cover_photo])
  end
end
```

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: if k[:is_cover_photo] && k[:cover_photo].blank?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that

Comment: It is quite a bit easier to help if you just copy and paste your error, then highlight which line it's referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the contents of the first if block with:

```
params[:point_of_interest][:albums_attributes].each do |key, value|
  if value[:is_cover_photo] && value[:cover_photo].present?
    @point_of_interest.update(:cover_photo => value[:cover_photo])
  end
end
redirect_to @point_of_interest
```

**EDIT**: Edited to use present? instead of blank? based on comments from OP.

Comment: This allows the album's cover photo to update but @point_of_interest's :cover_photo is not updated. Any ideas why?

Comment: Are you actually wanting that second line to read: if value[:is_cover_photo] && value[:cover_photo].present?

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I did not correctly understand how .blank? worked. Replacing .blank? with .present? fixed my issue.

Comment: I've edited the answer to use present? based on this thread. Thanks for accepting my answer.